# Discord bot specific word counter

Tags: python, discord

How do I make my discord bot count how many times "XD" been said by a user,and then on command show how many times the user has said the word . I haven't been able to find a tutorial for this anywhere, so I hope to find help from here.

Comment: This question should be closed, see point 4: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

You may find API documentation of how to process each message. Any message you receive has data of who sent it and from what server (please read the documentation). You may use some kind of dictionary to store those data (or some database to avoid reset upon shutting down). That will do the job.